# Argument type [CVarArgType] does not conform expected type CVarArgType

Tags: swift, arguments, extension-methods

I have this extension:

```
extension String {
    func localized() -> String {
        //... irrelevant code 
    }

    func localizedFormat(arguments: CVarArgType...) -> String {
        return String(format: localized(), arguments: arguments)
    }
}
```

This gives the error in the question title on line 2:

```
private static func tr(key: String, _ arguments: CVarArgType...) -> String {
    return key.localizedFormat(arguments)
}
```

But when I copy the `localizedFormat` implementation, it works:

```
private static func tr(key: String, _ arguments: CVarArgType...) -> String {
    return String(format: key.localized(), arguments: arguments)
}
```

The question is how the second implementation of `tr` worked, not the first

Comment: Swift Varargs are **only** for the programmer! You cannot pass an array to a method expecting a varargs. What you have at hand in the first `tr`-implementation is a `[CVarArgType]` which is not convertible to a varargs.

Comment: I'm confused. How does the other one works?

Comment: What other one? You mean the String initializer? Probably via method overloading

Comment: I just copied the implementation and it worked. This looks odd. But I get it.